# regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word within a specific number of character in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match the line which contains one specific string (such as "qwe") and does not contain other multiple words (such as "dfg" or "qq") within some specific number of characters from the specific string ("qwe").
I can use grep or other program languages, but I tried to use bash script and regular expression.

Input:

```
qweisdfg
qwe is dfg
dfg
qwe
qwe is qq
```

Desired output:

```
qwe is dfg
dfg
qwe
qwe is qq
```

My code (test.sh) is shown below;

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in `cat ./test2.txt`
do
    echo "$x";
    if [[ $x =~ ^.*"$1".\{0,3\}(dfg|qq).*$ ]]; then
        echo "ok"
    fi
done
```

I used this code like this;

```
./test.sh qwe
```

Comment: How come `dfg` is an expected output line? It does not contain `qwe`. You must be expecting `qwe is dfg`, `qwe` and `qwe is qq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" == *"$1"* && ! "$line" =~ "$1".{0,3}(dfg|qq) ]]; then
     echo "$line";
  fi
done < ./test2.txt
```

Output:

```
qwe is dfg
qwe
qwe is qq
```

The `"$line" == *"$1"*` part makes sure there is `qwe` is present in the current line, and `&& ! "$line" =~ "$1".{0,3}(dfg|qq)` fails the match if there is `dfg` or `qq` after any 0 to 3 chars after `qwe`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistant. Why this code fail to pick up the 3rd line "dfg" while the line "dfg" dose not contain "qwe?"

Comment: @rrkk Because your requirement is ***match the line which contains one specific string (such as "qwe")***. No `qwe`, no match.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing.